# how to echoing value but i want the row on it heading place

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I have a table like this.

[image]

but I want the data on the 'debit' column is on it own place.

this is what Iwant :

[image]

this is my current code :

```
<?php
foreach ($jurnal->result_array() as $data){
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$data['no_akun']."</td>
        <td>".$data['nm_akun']."</td>";
        if ($data['nm_akun'] == 'kredit'){
            echo "
                <td></td>
                <td>".$data['posisi_dr_cr']."</td>
            ";

        }else{
            echo "
                <td>".$data['posisi_dr_cr']."</td> 
                <td></td>
            ";
        }
    "</tr>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think most likely the first `<tr>` (the green row) has more than 4 `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

td tag width is the same of the content that it envelopes, so an empty td will be 0px width.

Try adding width="25%" to your td tags, like this:

**EDITED:**

```
foreach ($jurnal->result_array() as $data){
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td width=\"25%\">".$data['no_akun']."</td>
                    <td width=\"25%\">".$data['nm_akun']."</td>";
                    if ($data['nm_akun'] == 'kredit'){
                        echo "
                            <td width=\"25%\"></td>
                            <td width=\"25%\">".$data['posisi_dr_cr']."</td>
                        ";

                    }else{
                        echo "
                            <td width=\"25%\">".$data['posisi_dr_cr']."</td> 
                            <td width=\"25%\"></td>
                        ";
                    }
                "</tr>
                ";
            }
        ?>
```

Notice that width="25%" is typed inside a String, so double quote characters must have \ characters in order to be escaped.

Comment: still cant, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. if you are using bootstrap css, you can use `text-left` in the class.

```
<?php
foreach ($jurnal->result_array() as $data){
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td class='text-left'>".$data['no_akun']."</td>
        <td class='text-left'>".$data['nm_akun']."</td>";
        if ($data['nm_akun'] == 'kredit'){
            echo "
                <td class='text-left'></td>
                <td class='text-left'>".$data['posisi_dr_cr']."</td>
            ";

        }else{
            echo "
                <td class='text-left'>".$data['posisi_dr_cr']."</td> 
                <td class='text-left'></td>
            ";
        }
    "</tr>
    ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
<?php
foreach ($jurnal->result_array() as $data){
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$data['no_akun']."</td>
        <td>".$data['nm_akun']."</td>";
        if ($data['nm_akun'] == 'kredit'){
            echo "
                <td>&nbsp</td>
                <td>".$data['posisi_dr_cr']."</td>
            ";

        }else{
            echo "
                <td>".$data['posisi_dr_cr']."</td> 
                <td>&nbsp</td>
            ";
        }
    "</tr>
    ";
}
?>
```